# number of paths 2d array

Tags: java

I have to find the shortest path from one index to the other.

In order to progress a index the index must be a "neighbor" with same value inside the index as the one next to it. I have to create a function that calculates all possible paths recursively and then puts all in a matrix.

My thoughts so far where to use the flood fill algorithm and somehow count each path.

ok so ive been sitting here quite a while trying to figure out how to do this and so far I came with this idea: create a duplicate array that in each index will show me the distance from my initial node. im not sure if I am doing this correctly so a little help is needed, this is what I wrote:

```
public static int[][] createdistancematrix(int[][] map, int i, int j) {
    int[][] temp = new int[map.length][map[0].length];
    map[i][j] = 0;
    int count = 0;
    filldistance(temp, i, j,count);

    return temp;
}

public static int[][] filldistance(int[][] temp, int i, int j,int count) {
    if ((i<temp.length) && (i>=0) && (j<temp.length) && (j>=0)) {

        temp[i][j] = count;
        count++;

        //recursive call for north east west south.

        filldistance(temp, i-1,j, count);
        filldistance(temp, i+1,j, count);
        filldistance(temp, i,j-1, count);
        filldistance(temp, i,j+1, count);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: post what you have tried please. I'm sure you've done something

Comment: you're asking two questions here: do you *need* to calculate all possible paths, or is your goal to simply find the shortest path?

Comment: I think one derives from the other. I will find the shortest path after I found all path lengths. first I have to write a recursive function that gives me all possible lengths of paths.

Comment: In your comment to Michael, you ruled out Dijkstras because it doesn't give *all possible* paths, but it does find the shortest path. Breadth first search will find the shortest path in an unweighted graph - Floyd-Warshalls algorithm will find the shortest path but not return any detail about the path. You should probably ask your professor to clarify the assignment to you - maybe there's a specific way he/she expects you to complete the task.

Comment: this is exactly the point im not allowed to ask my professor anything related to the assignment. I don't understand why but these are the rules. last time I asked he told me "its in java". so you say there is no algorithm that can give me all paths???

Comment: traversing all possible paths is a trivial recursive task - look up Depth First Search.

Answer (score 0):

The 2D matrix you're given is actually called an adjacency matrix. I think you'll find Dijkstra's algorithm useful, or a Breadth First Search which stops once you've found the target vertex.

Comment: from what I researched the Dijkstra's algorithm gives you shortest path period not giving all possible paths to the vertex. on the other hand breadth first search seems more suitable. thanks a lot!